# content editor script isn't working on list view page

Tags: jquery, list-view-web-part

This is very strange. I have a script attached to a content editor that spruces up the status column of a particular list. However , I'm trying to achieve the same thing with that particular List's default view page since It will be bad user experience if the rendering is only being done on the front page. However, the script that I'm attaching (which is a new script for that page ) isn't working at all. Please can somebody throw some light on whats going on?

Notes:

1. I'm attaching a link a html file to the content editor and this file is stored in a separate document library
2. Working with Sharepoint 2010 so unfortunately don't have the JSlink feature availabe.
3. All the site collections are based on 2010, but they're being hosted on sharepoint 2013, so even XSL files have gone out the window because sharepoint designer 2013 dosent generate the xsl code when i click the custom xsl feature.

So, jquery is my only option, and since It's working perfectly fine on the default.aspx page, I really want to get it to work on the list view page too.

Tested it with the following code but nothing happens:

```
<script>
alert("hello");
<script>
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of your HTML file that's serving as the content of the Content Editor Web Part?